# Global values: Define as service or define abstract Controller class?

Tags: symfony, inheritance, service, twig

In my Symfony2 app, I want to globally fetch a value from my database on each template and don't want to call on each Controller. I know I could define that as a service and inject that service into my twig templates (by defining it as a twig global).

Is that the common and recommended way? Or should I rather create an abstract Controller class where I fetch that value in my constructor and then inherit from all my other Controllers?

*Note: It is actually not a static value that is the same for all users, but it is a user specific value which is different for each user.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this variables are used to render the same spot on your page you can render an [embedded controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). Like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller('YourBundle:User:stats')) }}
</div>
```

This will inject whole output of YourBundle/UserController/statsAction to the #sidebar div. Inside this action you can extract all inforamtion that you need.

If you need to use this variables in other way maybe you should look at [response event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event).

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach (thus +1), but I read about the fact that calling the render function in twig slows down on performance. So I'm still waiting for other answers. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with event listeners?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

An event listener can be used to inject twig globals.

```
class ModelEventListener extends ContainerAware implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(
            array('doProject',       -1300),
        ),
        KernelEvents::VIEW => array(
            array('doView',          -2100),
        ),
    );
}
public function doProject(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $project = $whatever_is_needed_to_find_the_project();

    if (!$project) throw new NotFoundHttpException('Project not found ' . $projectSearch);

    // Add to request
    $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('project',$project);

    // Give all twig templates access to project
    $twig = $this->container->get('twig');
    $twig->addGlobal('project',$project);
}
# services.yml
cerad_core__model__event_listener:
    class:  '%cerad_core__model__event_listener__class%'
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but it's "too much" in my case.

Comment: No problem.  Understanding kernel events is key step on the way to understanding the framework.  Come back to this when you have the time.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a user value like you said you can get `app.user.XXX` on every twig template you need without processing nothing ;)

Comment: I have to fetch this value from the database and cannot declare the method in the User entity. But I'll +1 your answer as it is valid in general. Thanks

Comment: So embedded controler is a good practice http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: Do you know if writing a service and injecting it into a twig template (as twig global) is significantly faster than embedded controllers?

Comment: A controllers is basically service. If you absolutely want speed, take a lok to the twig extension (but for me it's a really bad practice to transfer logic to view ...) http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html